# Android: How to get all edit text values when using custom array adapter and listview?

Tags: android

I am a dummy in java and android programming, I only coded through tutorials found in the net. Now, I have to implement an application that counts inventory for each model. I was able to do button clicks and editing values in edit text. My problem now is that I do not know how to get all values of the edit text in the custom list view. I have searched for solutions but there is something I am doing wrong. Please find my codes below:

Model_ListAdapter.java

```
package com.hondaph.digitaldcr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by bh00001693 on 10/02/2017.
 */

public class Model_ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_List> {
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Model_List> modelList1;
    private int mViewResourceId;
    private int lastPosition = -1;
    private int countInvty[], countRtl[], rtlInput;
    private String invtyInput;

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtvMdlname;
        TextView txtvMdlcode;
        EditText edtInvty;
        EditText edtRtl;
        Button btnSave;
    }

    public Model_ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Model_List> modelList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, modelList);
        this.modelList1 = modelList;
        mContext = context;
        this.countInvty = new int[modelList.size()];
        this.countRtl = new int[modelList.size()];
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        final Model_List modelList = modelList1.get(position);

        if (modelList != null) {
            final View result;
            final String modelname = modelList.getModelname();
            String modelcode = modelList.getModelcode();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //holder.txtvMdlname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvMdlname);
            //holder.txtvMdlcode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvMdlcode);
            //holder.edtInvty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtInvty);
            //holder.edtRtl = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edtRtl);
           // holder.btnSave = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

            //Inventory
            ImageButton btnAddInvty = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddInvty);
            ImageButton btnMinusInvty = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMinusInvty);
            btnAddInvty.setTag(position);
            btnMinusInvty.setTag(position);

            //Retail
            ImageButton btnAddRtl = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddRtl);
            ImageButton btnMinusRtl = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMinusRtl);
            btnAddRtl.setTag(position);
            btnMinusRtl.setTag(position);

            result = convertView;
            convertView.setTag(convertView);

            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                    (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.loading_down_anim : R.anim.loading_up_anim); //if position is > lastPosition, use loading down anim, else use loading up
            result.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;

            holder.txtvMdlname.setText(modelname);
            holder.txtvMdlcode.setText(modelcode);
            holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));
            holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));

            btnAddInvty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //hide soft keyboard
                    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                    invtyInput = holder.edtInvty.getText().toString();

                    if (String.valueOf(invtyInput).matches("")) {
                        countInvty[position] = countInvty[position] + 1;
                        holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));
                    } else {
                        countInvty[position] = Integer.parseInt(invtyInput) + 1;
                        holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));
                    }

                    //hide soft keyboard
                    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.edtInvty.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            });

            btnMinusInvty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //hide soft keyboard
                    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                    invtyInput = holder.edtInvty.getText().toString();

                    if (String.valueOf(invtyInput).matches("")) {
                        countInvty[position] = countInvty[position] - 1;
                        holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));
                    } else {
                        countInvty[position] = Integer.parseInt(invtyInput) - 1;
                        holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));
                    }

                    //hide soft keyboard
                    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.edtInvty.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }
            });


            btnAddRtl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //hide soft keyboard
                    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                    rtlInput = Integer.parseInt(holder.edtRtl.getText().toString());

                    if (rtlInput == 0) {
                        countRtl[position] = countRtl[position] + 1;
                        holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));
                    } else {
                        countRtl[position] = rtlInput + 1;
                        holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));
                    }

                    //hide soft keyboard
                    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.edtRtl.getWindowToken(), 0);


                }
            });

            btnMinusRtl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //hide soft keyboard
                    InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

                    rtlInput = Integer.parseInt(holder.edtRtl.getText().toString());

                    if (rtlInput == 0) {
                        countRtl[position] = countRtl[position] - 1;
                        holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));
                    } else {
                        countRtl[position] = rtlInput - 1;
                        holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));
                    }

                    //hide soft keyboard
                    inputMgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(holder.edtRtl.getWindowToken(), 0);

                }
            });

            //to retain values during scroll down
            holder.edtInvty.setText(String.valueOf(countInvty[position]));

            holder.edtInvty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                    countInvty[position] = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
                    holder.edtInvty.setTag(countInvty[position]);

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });

            holder.edtRtl.setText(String.valueOf(countRtl[position]));
            holder.edtRtl.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int before, int count) {
                    countRtl[position] = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

`
ViewListContents.java

```
public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper DB;
    ArrayList<Model_List> modelList;
    ListView listView;
    Model_List model_List;
    int count2 = 0;
    Button btnSave;
    private Context mContext;
    final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewcontents_layout);

        DB = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        DB.openDataBase();

        modelList = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = DB.getHondaModels();
        int numRows = cursor.getCount();
        if (numRows == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewListContents.this, "There are no records in database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //model_List = new Model_List(cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
                model_List = new Model_List(cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6));
                modelList.add(model_List);
            }

            final Model_ListAdapter adapter = new Model_ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, modelList);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstvSummary);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            ViewGroup headerView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, listView, false);
            listView.addHeaderView(headerView);

            ViewGroup footer = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, listView, false);

            listView.addFooterView(footer, null, false);

            Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                }
            });


        }


    }
}
```

MainMenu.java

public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button rtl_invty, upload, updateDB, summary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    rtl_invty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRtl_Invty);
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    updateDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateDB);
    summary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSummary);

    rtl_invty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, ViewListContents.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: why not declear a `Map<Int,List<String>>` key is position ,values is collection

Comment: thank you abby for the suggestion. I have tried solutions like that as well but since I am new at this platform I do not know how to incorporate it in the above code =(